# React-Native - New App closed immediately

Tags: react-native, npm, adb

i get an new PC and i will install React-Native.
I Installed the following Libraries:

- react-native-cli: 2.0.1
- react-native: 0.60.5
- npm: 6.9.0
- nodeJS: v10.16.3
- Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41

If i run the command "`react-native run-android`" then the Node Server does not start immediately. If i run "`react-native start`" and in another terminal "`react-native run-android`", then the run command will close.

[image: error]

Another Problem is, that the Node Package Server dont open automaticially if i run "`react-native run-android`"

i hope someone can help me with my problem

Answer (score 1):

A similar bug was reported in React Native's official repository for version 0.60. It was an issue in *react-native-cli*.

See this [bug report](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25509).

Solution for your problem is to update *react-native-cli* to the latest version.

[How to update the cli?](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli#updating-the-cli)

Comment: It does not worked. I already have all modules in the latest version. Do you know an other solution?